# Drop missing values for one column

Tags: r, missing-data

I am using this [data](https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/nlsdata_1.dat) in R and I need to drop missing values for `lwage76`. I tried the following code:

```
nlsdata[!is.na(nlsdata$lwage76),]
```

but it does not work; I still have at least one "." value in `lwage76`.

Comment: the `.` is not `NA`

Comment: When you read in the data, there's an argument to tell the function how to recognize missing values. For the `read.table` function, it's `na.strings`. Set `na.strings="."` and these values will be converted to `NA` (the R missing data code) when you read in the data. Then you're code will work.

Comment: You can also recode missing values after reading in the data. In your case it would be `nlsdata$lwage76[nlsdata$lwage76=="."] = NA`. Run this before running the code in your question and the code will work. However, in that case, you'll also need to convert `lwage` from character (or factor, if you didn't set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when you read in the data) to numeric, because the `.` values will cause R to think those columns are strings rather than numbers.

Comment: @eipi10 Thank you! I used it and it worked!